# How to activate ctrl+a in linux Opensuse?

Tags: opensuse, opensuse-12.2

Recently I installed Linux openSUSE 12.2 on my laptop.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is not working correctly. I used to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to mark everything, all the text, and etc. Here, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> moves the cursor to the beginning of the text. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I use the Gnome user interface and I get this behavior on Chrome. For example when I want to select the URL address I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> but, the cursor moves to the beginning of the URL.

Comment: What display manager, oddly enough that could come in to play.  Thanks!

Comment: And in what application are you getting this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I use 12.2 with a variety of GUIs - the only way to not get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> working on my setup is not to have focus on the specific pane when pressing that key combo.  This may sound way too basic but try clicking the cursor on the pave you want highlighted...